# Color axis labels in Frappe Charts (perhaps using correct CSS selector)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to color every x and y axis labels in this frappe chart:

[image]

I tried finding the CSS selectors using the chrome devtools, but a single `text` element (one of the three x axis labels you see in the image) has the following CSS selector:

`#frappe-chart-0 > div > svg > g > g.x.axis > g:nth-child(3) > text`

My page has multiple (three) frappe charts, with an arbitary number of `nth-child` elements. So optimally, I would want some CSS selector like this with wildcards:

`#frappe-chart-* > div > svg > g > g.*.axis > g:nth-child(*) > text`

Unfortunately, that is not possible. Is there another way?

Comment: Could you describe more what you want to achieve. Do you want to color every x axis marker in every chart or just in the first chart for example. Why did you select nth-child, why not just leave that out?

Comment: I want to color every x and y axis marker in every chart. I did not select the n-th child myself, I simply copied the CSS selector from chrome devtools. I have updated the post.

Comment: So just leave out the : nth-child if you want every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by using the following CSS selectors:

```css
[id*="frappe-chart-"] > div > svg > g > g.y.axis > g > text {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
[id*="frappe-chart-"] > div > svg > g > g.x.axis > g > text {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The wildcard id selector selects all frappe charts on the page. Furthermore, by removing the `nth-child(3)` selector all axis texts are selected.

Comment: Hi, I know that you are answering your own question, an that's ok. Please explain why this works, this is a specific requirement of this site. Read useful docs here: [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I added some more clarification on what I did.